# Factor Denominator of Fraction

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, factorization

How do I get Mathematica to factor the denominator of a fraction? For example, to turn
$$\frac{1}{s^2+3s+2}$$
into
$$\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}.$$
I tried `Factor`, but it did not work. Ultimately, I also want to use `Apart`, but that doesn't seem to work without factoring the denominator.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Thank you for formatting your question for readability.  In the future, please also post any expression that people may want to copy as Mathematica code.  LaTeX great because it is good for humans to read, but we also want to be able to paste in to Mathematica.

Comment: [`Factor` works for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gTdna.png)

Comment: @Szabolcs Unrelated with the OP: do you create the image & upload it manually, or is it automated by MMA or other?

Comment: @anderstood Take a look at this: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1521/12

Comment: I tried version 8 and 11 and in both cases `Factor` just works (as Szabolcs wrote) . I must assume you made an error in entering your expression. Perhaps you used the Python form of `s**2` for exponentiation (it is `s^2` in Mathematica)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expr = 1/(s^2 + 3 s + 2);
MapAt[Factor, expr, 1]
(*   1/((1 + s) (2 + s))   *)
```

Have fun!